# How to connect a signal with extra arguments in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

This would be the part of the code that gives me an error.

```
for y in range(rows):
        var row = []
        for x in range(columns):
            var label = Button.new()
            row.append(label)
            self.add_child(label)
            label.group = "letters"  # Asignar el grupo "letters" a los botones
            label.connect("pressed", self, "_on_LetterPressed", [x, y])  # Conectar la señal de presionado
        grid.append(row)
```

In Godot 3 the connect works fine but the label.groups doesn't work, how can I do this in Godot 4?

Comment: It appears that any details about your error are incredibly confidential as you are not willing to tell us anything about it. Unfortunately, that makes it rather difficult for anyone to actually help you...

Answer (score 6):

### How to upgrade `connect` from Godot 3 to Godot 4

Let us start with the simple case. If in Godot 3 you connect like this:

*Godot 3*

```
object.connect("signal_name", self, "method_name")
```

You can do the same in Godot 4, by making a `Callable`:

*Godot 4*

```
object.connect("signal_name", Callable(self, "method_name"))
```

By the way, Godot will make a `Callable` for us like this:

*Godot 4*

```
object.connect("signal_name", method_name)
```

Furthermore, you can use the `Signal` like this:

*Godot 4*

```
object.signal_name.connect(method_name)
```

---

**With extra arguments**

However, in your case you have extra arguments:

*Godot 3*

```
object.connect("signal_name", self, "method_name", [extra, arguments])
```

What we are going to do in Godot 4 is bind them to the `Callable` like this:

*Godot 4*

```
object.connect("signal_name", Callable(self, "method_name").bind([extra, arguments]))
```

Or like this:

*Godot 4*

```
object.connect("signal_name", method_name.bind([extra, arguments]))
```

Or like this:

*Godot 4*

```
object.signal_name.connect(method_name.bind([extra, arguments]))
```